# Finding a closed form for $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=k}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^k}{k^3\binom{n+k}{k}\binom{n}{k}}(\frac1{n^2}-\frac1{(n+1)^2})\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation, binomial-coefficients

> Consider the sum $$\sum_{n=k}^{N} \frac{1}{\binom{n+k}{k}\binom{n}{k}}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right) $$
> Using the above or otherwise I need a closed form for $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(-1)^k}{k^3 \binom{n+k}{k}\binom{n}{k}}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)\right) $$

I tried as follows: Denote $$S_{N,k}:=\sum_{n=k}^{N} \frac{1}{\binom{n+k}{k}\binom{n}{k}}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right) $$

On writing the formula for $n\choose k$ we get $$S_{N,k}:=\sum_{n=k}^{N} \frac{(n-k)!}{(n+k)!}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right) $$
Now $$\frac{(n-k)!}{(n+k)!}=\frac{(n-k)(n-k-1)!}{(n+k)!} $$
Using partial fractions we have
$$\frac{(n-k-1)!}{(n+k)!}=\frac{1}{(n-k)...(n+k)}=\frac{1}{(2k)!(n-k)}-\frac{1}{(2k-1)!1!(n-k+1)}+\frac{1}{(2k-2)!2!(n-k+2)}-... $$
So we have $$\frac{(n-k-1)!}{(n+k)!}=\frac{1}{(2k)!}\sum_{m=0}^{2k}\frac{(-1)^m \binom{2k}{m}}{n-k+m}$$
Plugging the above partial fraction decomposition in $S_{N,k}$ we get  $$S_{N,k}=\frac{1}{(2k)!}\sum_{n=k}^{N} \left(\sum_{m=0}^{2k}\frac{(-1)^m \binom{2k}{m} (n-k)}{n-k+m}\right)\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right) $$
$$S_{N,k}=\frac{1}{(2k)!}\sum_{n=k}^{N} \left(\sum_{m=0}^{2k}(-1)^m \binom{2k}{m} \left(1-\frac{m}{n-k+m}\right)\right)\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right) $$
Now since $$\sum_{m=0}^{2k}(-1)^m \binom{2k}{m}=0$$
So we get $$S_{N,k}=-\frac{1}{(2k)!}\sum_{n=k}^{N} \left(\sum_{m=1}^{2k} \frac{(-1)^m\ m \ \binom{2k}{m}}{n-k+m}\right)\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right) $$
After this I am unable to simplify further. Please help me to find the sum.

**Edit** Using the above or otherwise I need a closed form for $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(-1)^k}{k^3 \binom{n+k}{k}\binom{n}{k}}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)\right) $$

Comment: This looks like it wants a telescoping step or two, have you already considered this direction?

Comment: @abiessu No, I have not considered this direction. Please think over this direction

Comment: @Max: What makes you think that the sum *has* a closed form? Is this a textbook exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is not an answer - just observations*

Let

$$a_k=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^3 \binom{n+k}{k}\binom{n}{k}}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)$$ Computing the very first terms
$$a_k=b_k - \frac{2\, \zeta(3)}{k^2}$$ where the first $b_k$ form the sequence
$$\left\{2,\frac{29}{48},\frac{5191}{19440},\frac{72703}{483840},
   \frac{7270009}{75600000},\frac{47982293}{718502400},\frac{305647
   00141}{622961539200}\right\}$$
$$S_p=\sum_{k=1}^p a_k=-2\, \zeta (3)\, H_p^{(2)}+\sum_{k=1}^p b_k$$

The first terms of the summation are
$$\left\{2,\frac{125}{48},\frac{6977}{2430},\frac{13157111}{4354560
   },\frac{8484914699}{2721600000},\frac{71499992923}{22453200000
   },\frac{3218912736881}{995499618750}\right\}$$ which *looks* very much like an hyperbolic function.

Using the empirical
$$\sum_{k=1}^p b_k=\alpha -\frac \beta{p+\gamma}$$ we have with $R^2=0.999999986$

$$\begin{array}{|llll}
\hline
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Std Error} &
   \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 \alpha & 3.55728 & 0.00048 & \{3.55612,3.55845\} \\
 \beta  & 2.45307 & 0.00347 & \{2.44458,2.46156\} \\
 \gamma & 0.57511 & 0.00192 & \{0.57042,0.57979\} \\
\end{array}$$

So, the infinite sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \sim \alpha - \frac{\pi ^2 }{3}\zeta (3)$$ for a suitable $\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

The transformation of $S_{N,k}$ needs to be revised somewhat, since we have
\begin{align*}
\binom{n+k}{k}\binom{n}{k}&=\frac{(n+k)!}{n!k!}\,\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\\
&=\frac{(2k)!}{k!k!}\,\frac{(n+k)!}{(2k)!(n-k)!}=\binom{2k}{k}\binom{n+k}{n-k}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain from (1)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{S_{N,k}}&\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=k}^N\binom{n+k}{k}^{-1}\binom{n}{k}^{-1}
> \left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)}\\
> &=\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}\sum_{n=k}^{N}\binom{n+k}{n-k}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)\tag{2}\\
> &=\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}\sum_{n=k}^{N}(n+k+1)\int_{0}^1z^{n-k}(1-z)^{2k}\,dz
> \left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)\tag{3}\\
> &=\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}\int_0^1\frac{(1-z)^{2k}}{z^k}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n=k}^N(n+k+1)\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)z^n}\,dz\\
> \end{align*}

Regrettably, I do not see a nice simplification of the inner sum. We can rewrite it using the *[Lerch transcendent](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html)*. We have for instance
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=k}^N\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)z^n
&=z^k\left(\Phi(z,2,k)-\Phi(z,2,k+1)\right)\\
&\qquad-z^{N+1}\left(\Phi(z,2,N+1)-\Phi(z,2,N+2)\right)
\end{align*}
but it's rather just another representation, not a simplification of the sum.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we apply the binomial identity (1).
- In (3) we write the reciprocal of a binomial coefficient using the *[beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)*
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{n}{k}^{-1}=(n+1)\int_0^1z^k(1-z)^{n-k}\,dz
  \end{align*}

Comment: But this is not a closed form for the sum.

Comment: @Max: Yes, it's more a revision of your calculation. The representation via Lerch transcendents rather indicates there is no closed form.